# Can we run awk/sed commands in another awk command?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have the following string:

```html
<T"4567">Dummy Data</Test>
<T"0023"><Tag1>Dummy</Tag1></Test>
>DummyData<T"0001"><Tag2>asdad</Tag2><Tag3>bla</Tag3><Tag4>Dummy Data</Tag4></Test>
RandomString<T"0014">Dummy2 </Test>
```

I filtered out this string from a big file with the following command:

```
 awk '{for(tag=1;tag<=NF;tag++){if($tag~/"...."/){print $tag}}}' Big_FILE
```

to retrieve all the rows with `<T"dddd">` format.

Now I want to match all the ending `</Test>` tags with the value from the beginning `<T"dddd">` tags. **Note that we have one pair on each line**.
Can I use another `awk` for `$tag` ? I want to parse all the rows and store the value between `<T"` and `">` delimiters. For each row, I also want to use this value to overwrite with `sed` the paired `</Test>` tag.

In the end, it should look like this:

```html
<T4567>Dummy Data</T4567>
<T0023><Tag1>Dummy</Tag1></T0023>
>DummyData<T0001><Tag2>asdad</Tag2><Tag3>bla</Tag3><Tag4>Dummy Data</Tag4></T0001>
RandomString<T0014>Dummy2 </T0014>
```

I was thinking to use something like this:

```
awk '{for(tag=1;tag<=NF;tag++){if($tag~/"...."/)
                  {print $tag
                   awk -v '[<T" ">]' '{print $tag_new}' $tag
                   sed -i -e 's/</Test>/</T$tag_new>/g' $tag
                   sed -i -e 's/<T"/<T/g' $tag
                   sed -i -e 's/">/>/g' $tag
                   }}}
```

But as you can see I'm not familiar with `awk` and `sed` . Is there any recommended way to do this complex (for me) filter and replace process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling out to awk or sed or perl from awk or perl is never encouraged.

In this case, all you need is:

```
perl -pe 's{<T"(\d+)">(.*?)</Test>}{<T$1>$2</T$1>}g' file
```

producing

```
<T4567>Dummy Data</T4567>
<T0023><Tag1>Dummy</Tag1></T0023>
>DummyData<T0001><Tag2>asdad</Tag2><Tag3>bla</Tag3><Tag4>Dummy Data</Tag4></T0001>
RandomString<T0014>Dummy2 </T0014>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data is without double quotes except for the problem lines, you could use sed:

```
while IFS=\" read -r f1 f2 f3; do
        echo "${f1}${f2}$(echo "${f3}" |sed 's#</Test>#</T'${f2}'>#')"
done < Big_FILE
```